# Использование тега <a>

Tags: php

Использую тег `<a>` внутри таблицы, но почему-то не работает. Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
   echo "<td align=center>";
   echo $rs->Fields(1)->value;
   echo <a id="id_T" href="kol_ps.php"> $rs->Fields(1)->value</a>;
   echo "</td>";
```

Ошибка в браузере

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\aa\kol.php on line 51

Answer (score 2, accepted):

не правильно склеил стоку. используй (.) Двойные и одинарные кавычки

```
echo "<a id='id_T' href='kol_ps.php'>".$rs->Fields(1)->value."</a>";
```

Comment: все заработало спасибо большое Вам